# How to change TFS sender ID?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-alerts

I am using TFS hosted service at visualstudio.com

I have successfully setup Alerts for my account.

I am receiving these alert emails from this ID: admin@visualstudio.com

Is it possible to change it to reflect our company name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible as of the current date as replied on TFS support forum:

[Change of sender email address](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/TFService/thread/94fa425e-8fa8-4d93-a834-5547d2e4f543)

Comment: That's right. We do not currently expose the ability to control that email address.

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio Online update that was rolled out around 11-Dec-2013 changed the "sender" of the alert e-mails. They now appear as if they come from the most logical person, with their Visual Studio Online e-mail address.

For example, if Jane Joe changed something that would cause an alert, the alert is now coming from Jane Joe's Microsoft Account e-mail address instead of a generic admin@visualstudio.com (or other) account.

This isn't the first time Microsoft has changed the sender information in these e-mails, so no guarantee they will remain this way, but as of now that is how it works.